# SQL Select Distinct doesn't work

Tags: php, sql

I'm making a forum where i want the latest topics to be shown side-by-side with the category in which it belongs. However, when someone makes a topic in the same category twice it shows the category twice and the different topics on the right side.

This is somewhat right, but I want it to be only one category showing. I tried SQL `SELECT DISTINCT` for this, but it doesn't seem to work, can anyone tell me if there is something wrong in the syntax or if the problem lies elsewhere?

```
$sql = '
    SELECT DISTINCT topics.topic_id, topics.topic_subject, topics.topic_by, categories.cat_id, categories.cat_name, categories.cat_description FROM topics JOIN categories ON topics.topic_cat = categories.cat_id ORDER BY topics.topic_date DESC LIMIT 3
';
```

Also, I want to note that the reason for `LIMIT 3` is because this is from the homepage, where only 3 categories are supposed to show. The problem persists on both the homepage and the category page.

Comment: have you tried selecting by distinct cat_id? That would make more sense if you want to limit it to one per category

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text.

Comment: @FMashiro I could try that, but what would I change the syntax to?

Comment: @Mureinik I'm not ENTIRELY sure, i'm fairly new to this, but I think the answer would be MariaDB

Comment: $sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT topic_id,topic_subject,topic_by,cat_id,cat_name,cat_description FROM topics,categories JOIN categories ON topics.topic_cat = categories.cat_id ORDER BY topics.topic_date DESC LIMIT 3';

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting more than one column with `distinct` i.e.

```
SELECT DISTINCT topics.topic_id, topics.topic_subject, topics.topic_by, categories.cat_id, categories.cat_name, categories.cat_description
```

I don't think with so many columns you can differentiate `distinct` and `non distinct` values.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense, but I'm not sure what I should change it to and not have to query twice